# New to Git, why are there already so many configurations set in git config?

Tags: macos, terminal, git, macos-mojave

New to using git, and just downloaded it. Getting it set up and was surprised to find so many presets with `git config --list`? I thought nothing was supposed to be preset.

output of `git config --list`:

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
:
```

Comment: Where did you download it? You can edit/remove those anytime. Those may be just for "user convenience".

Comment: I got it from sourceforge, through the manual download link from git-scm.com

Comment: How do I remove them? I also don't understand what they are

Comment: I am not macOS user, but generally those configs are stored in `.gitconfig` file in user's home directory.

Comment: Here is the source code [git-osx-installer](https://github.com/timcharper/git_osx_installer/blob/master/assets/etc/gitconfig.default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download it from SourceForge instead of the official site (https://git-scm.com/downloads), it is probably just for convenience, as Biswapriyo says.

You can just erase all of that and start clean if you want. There is no problem with that. Just open your `.gitconfig` file with your favourite editor and erase everything or just the things that you don't understand. It is typically located at `~/.gitconfig`.

But there are some useful tools there, anyways. For example, everything starting with `alias` is a shortcut to writing less code.

For example, if you type

```
git lg
```

that will give you the same result as

```
git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

This will create a colored graph with a short commit message and some other info. It's very useful.

So it is very convenient, but you need to familiarise yourself first in my opinion. If you are totally new to git, I would recommend you to avoid aliases for a while and start using them as you feel the need to. Because if you try to use them now, it will be too much information.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you're seeing in that output are alias commands.

It doesn't hurt to have them, as they are just an alternative to legit commands.

For example `alias.cm=commit -m` allows you to type a command `git cm "some message"` and hit enter to execute the command. It's the exact same as using the full length command `git commit -m "some message"`

Another example of the shown output you can type `git master` to check out the master branch instead of having to type `git checkout master`

The alias commands that are listed will not be used if you do not use the shortcuts. If you're afraid of accidentally you can open up the `.gitconfig` in an editor of your choice and remove the configurations.

It's hard to see what else is there without seeing the full `git config --list` output.

If you want to look through each of, or at least ones you have questions about, you can read about them in the [git-config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Answer (score 1):

git configuration can be stored at multiple places:

- system wide (typically `/etc/gitconfig`)
- user wide (typically `~/.gitconfig`)
- and inside each git repository (at `.git/config`)

When you call `git config` it takes into account all of the above, in this order (later statements override earlier ones), and it will depend on where you are in the filesystem, because if you are in a git repository its configuration will be taken into account.

When you install `git`, the system-wide configuration can be already populated by default values that the maintainer of the git "package" you install feels useful. Your own personal configuration is probably empty, as are previous git repositories configuration except if you change them (and except for some default values like origin setting, etc.)

If you look at git config manual page, you see this:

```
   --global
       For writing options: write to global ~/.gitconfig file rather than the repository .git/config, write to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config file if this file exists and the ~/.gitconfig file doesn't.

       For reading options: read only from global ~/.gitconfig and from $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config rather than from all available files.

       See also the section called "FILES".

   --system
       For writing options: write to system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather than the repository .git/config.

       For reading options: read only from system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather than from all available files.

       See also the section called "FILES".

   --local
       For writing options: write to the repository .git/config file. This is the default behavior.

       For reading options: read only from the repository .git/config rather than from all available files.

       See also the section called "FILES".
```

And the "FILES" section tells:

```
   If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git config will search for configuration options:

   $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
       System-wide configuration file.

   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
       Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as
       support for this file was added fairly recently.

   ~/.gitconfig
       User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.

   $GIT_DIR/config
       Repository specific configuration file.
```

And also:

> The files are read in the order given above, with last value found taking precedence over values read earlier. When multiple values are taken then all values of a key from all files will be used.